# kentico localization macros in CSS

Tags: kentico

I'm trying to use macros in a CSS file (in site manager-> development).

This is my CSS code:

```
@import url('/CMSPages/GetResource.ashx?stylesheetname=sitecss{$=|en-US=eng$}');

a, a:visited, a:active {
  color:#407a1f;
}
....
```

This doesn't seem to work dynamically on the site as I switch between default culture and English.

The only time that it works is if I SAVE the CSS file (in site manager) while the site itself is in a certain culture.

In short: the macro "takes" the culture when the CSS file is saved and is not dynamic upon page loading.

How can I solve this?

THANKS :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot make you CSS code dynamic. However, you can do this easily as explained below:

- Kentico adds a special class to the body tag of the document. Check your source code and you will see that the body tag has a class ENUS if the current culture is en-US, ENGB if the current culture is en-GB and so on.
- Then you can change your CSS code accordingly by defining rules like:

  - body.ENUS .container { float: left; }
  - body.ENGB .container { float: right; }
  - body.FRFR .container { float: none; }

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In version 6 and later you can do it by
`@import url('/CMSPages/GetResource.ashx?stylesheetname=sitecss{%CurrentCulture%}');`
or you can directly resolve target CSS by
`{% CSS["<stylesheet code name>"] %}`
See more on http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/index.html?combining_stylesheets.htm